# Can't sign in using basic auth in spring boot security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

When I try to sign in using inmemory username and password it always throws up invalid.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao9vm.png)

This dialog box always shows up, even if I enter the correct username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in configureGlobal(.....) we need to use either passwordEncoder like **BCryptPasswordEncoder** or if we don't want to use any password encoder then we have to write like **password("{noop}password")** {noop} means use NoOpPasswordEncoder to validate this password.

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using inMemoryAuth, I am assuming that you are doing this to learn spring and your password is "password". In that case you should also let spring know that the clear text password that you have entered should be taken as-is, which is done by using a NoOpPasswordEncoder.

```
@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
               .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
               .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
```

NoOpPasswordEncoder will show up as deprecated since it is not intended to be used in general.